# Materiazile.css carousel not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="carousel carousel-slider center" data-indicators="true">
        <div class="carousel-fixed-item center">
            <a class="btn waves-effect white grey-text darken-text-2">button</a>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item red white-text" href="#one!">
            <h2>First Panel</h2>
            <p class="white-text">This is your first panel</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item amber white-text" href="#two!">
            <h2>Second Panel</h2>
            <p class="white-text">This is your second panel</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item green white-text" href="#three!">
            <h2>Third Panel</h2>
            <p class="white-text">This is your third panel</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item blue white-text" href="#four!">
            <h2>Fourth Panel</h2>
            <p class="white-text">This is your fourth panel</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.carousel.carousel-slider').carousel({ fullWidth: true });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's basically a copy-paste from the [official documentation](http://materializecss.com/carousel.html), and it works as expected on my desktop, but doesn't work on mobile devices (I'm on Android). Carousel is showing, but when I swipe on it nothing happens.

Example carousels from the official docs page http://materializecss.com/carousel.html work on my mobile devices just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using older jquery version. Try using jquery-3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I use latest jquery 3 version https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js.

It works fine in mobile as well.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="carousel carousel-slider center" data-indicators="true">
        <div class="carousel-fixed-item center">
            <a class="btn waves-effect white grey-text darken-text-2">button</a>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item red white-text" href="#one!">
            <h2>First Panel</h2>
            <p class="white-text">This is your first panel</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item amber white-text" href="#two!">
            <h2>Second Panel</h2>
            <p class="white-text">This is your second panel</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item green white-text" href="#three!">
            <h2>Third Panel</h2>
            <p class="white-text">This is your third panel</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item blue white-text" href="#four!">
            <h2>Fourth Panel</h2>
            <p class="white-text">This is your fourth panel</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.carousel.carousel-slider').carousel({ fullWidth: true });
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$(function(){$('.carousel').carousel();});
```